# Android EditText with inputType and Enter button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need make multiline EditText input with inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions" but leave Enter(new line) button in keyboard.

Problem i have is that when i put inputType attribute on edittext it changes enter button to next button.

so, is there way to have EditText with inputType attribute set and working enter button?

thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when I add inputType attribute it force EditText into singleline

I just added **textMultiLine** into inputType.

so it is `inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"` and it works

Answer (score 0):

You should check this XML property : [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) and its **actionDone** value

Comment: Sorry, it was not so clear. I need new line button not done button. i know about this imeOptions. I can use imeOptions="actionNone" to show enter(new line) button but when I click on that it inserts just space not new line. but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, so you may need android:singleLine="false" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: I see, edittext is multiline in default but if you set inputType it become singleLine somehow. enter(new line) button appeared again when I added textMultiLine into inputType.

Comment: In my case android:singleLine="false" doesnt work because it is overriden by inputType.